# How to speed up reload and development process with Sinatra/Ruby/Rack/Haml?

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra, haml

I am building a Sinatra site and, after trying [Shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun), I am using [Rerun](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) to reload my [Thin server](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) after editing files.

However, I am finding the development/feedback loop to be painfully time consuming. For example, making a small change to CSS, JavaScript or Haml files requires a 7-8 second wait for the server to reload before I can reload the page in my browser to see the changes. (My app is using [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) to manage assets etc.)

Ignoring these reloads is not quite possible as the page thus doesn't reflect the changes and would close the feedback loop entirely.

Is there any way to streamline this process or is everyone going through this wait every time they want to see a change reflected? Coming from a PHP/CSS/HTML background, I'm finding it rather painful to develop with Sinatra/HAML and am under the impression I am missing a core concept somehow?

Comment: Sinatra contains extensions, one of which is the Reloader: http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/reloader.html

Comment: You don't need to reload the server for static files, either.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't believe you have to reload the server to see changes to static files. So just save your changes and refresh the page for those.

Now when you need to change some backend stuff, I usually use the Shotgun gem. Assuming you're not on Windows, you can run `gem install shotgun` to install it, and then run `shotgun config.ru` to automatically start using Rack. Shotgun will automatically reload the server when you change any back-end stuff, and is noticeably faster than doing this manually. You can also run it with a straight Ruby file with `shotgun file.rb` should you desire.

You can check out the full Shotgun documentation and source at the [Shotgun repository](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun).

Comment: *I* never reload the server for changes in static files, nor for changes to files processed by Haml, unless I need new locals passed into the template.

Answer (score 0):

@Cereal - Thankyou, but I mentioned in the question I've tried using Shotgun but it running quite slowly too.

@the Tin Man - Thank you, it is good to know that changes to HAML do not require a reload.

I suppose after all this, some research led me to this article which was incredibly useful for implementing guard/rack livereload: [Lightning-Fast Sass Reloading](http://blog.55minutes.com/2013/01/lightning-fast-sass-reloading-in-rails-32/)

After going through this process, everything is running very well, the live reload functionality is amazing. As this article is for rails, I had to (instead of in `config/environments/development.rb`) add:

**config.ru**

```
require 'rack-livereload'
use Rack::LiveReload
```

The big thing, however, was realising that `sprockets` does indeed deliver altered `.js, .css` etc without requiring a server reload, even if it is minified/concatenated. Thus, a huge speedup could have been generated by forcing rerun to ignore `.haml, .scss, .css, .js` which ended up being as simple as fixing my `rerun` command to ignore these files:

`rerun rackup config.ru -i '**/*.{haml,scss,css,js}'`

However, I'm very happy using `guard/livereload` after all, and in the end, the combination is very good:

**Final solution (after configuration)**

Run server with altered rerun command (so server reloads when actually altering .rb files):
`rerun rackup config.ru -i '**/*.{haml,scss,css,js}'`

Run guard to monitor for asset changes/livereload:
`bundle exec guard -P livereload`